# How to get model output from tensorflow model without knowing its name in advance?

Tags: tensorflow, output

So I frequently run models with different architectures, but have code intended to apply to all of them which runs inference off the saved models.  Thus, I will be calling `eval()` on the last layer of this model, like this:

```
yhat = graph.get_tensor_by_name("name_of_my_last_layer:0")
decoded_image = yhat.eval(session=sess, feed_dict={x : X})
```

However, without arduous log parsing, I don't know exactly what the last layer is named, and I'm currently hand-coding it.  I've considered creating a generic 'output' tensor in my graph but that seems wasteful/brittle.  What is the better way?

Comment: Do you have MetaGraphDef of these models? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.proto

This proto contains meta information of a model such as variables, train ops. I'm not sure about the last layer, though.

Comment: @YaoZhang Sure I can get a list of all the ops, but if you've ever looked at that, it includes so many different things that it's actually still pretty hard to pick out the last network layer from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to either making the layer you want to analyse a model output or to fix its name (by passing the name= keyword argument to the layer function when creating the layer) to be a known string.